# How to extract the string values "Hello" and "World" from the XML using Python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.6

I need to extract the strings "Hello" and "World" using Python 2.6. Please advice.

```
<Translate_Array_Request>
  <App_Id />
  <From>language-code</From>
  <Options>
    <Category xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" >string-value</Category>
    <Content Type xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2">text/plain</ContentType>
    <Reserved Flags xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" />
    <State xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" >int-value</State>
    <Uri xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" >string-value</Uri>
    <User xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" >string-value</User>
  </Options>
  <Texts>
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">**Hello**</string>
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">**World**</string>
    </Texts>
  <To>language-code</To>
</Translate_Array_Request>
```

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple libraries in python that let you parse and extract data from XML. One way would be to use the [ElementTree XML python API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Assuming the input is saved as a string `xml_data`, this is what you do:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
>>> texts = root.find('Texts')
>>> for data in texts:
...     print data.text
...
**Hello**
**World**
```

Answer (score 0):

with xml package, do something like:

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

```
def getTags( xml )
  root = ET.fromstring( xml )
  res = []

  for tag in root.iter("string"):
    res.append(tag.text)

  return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using minidom,

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
def getTags(xml)
  root = minidom.parseString(xml)
  return [i.firstChild.nodeValue for i in root.getElementsByTagName('string')]
```

Comment: For testing purpose, I'm saving the XMLRequest in a temp.xml file. Where should I specify the file name in the above code?